# missing encodePacket / .abi + keccak256

Tags: solidity, abi, keccak, encryption

I'm not 100% sure how to describe my issue, total noob following the BlindAuction solidity tutorial and stuck unable to compile. any help is much appreciated.

```
 function generateBlindedBidBytes32(uint value, bool fake) public view returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacket(value, fake));
    }
```

[image: Image of error thrown on remix]

Answer (score 1):

You're just making a typo. It's `abi.encodePacked()`, and not `abi.encodePacket()`.